# DXF file import in Altium, can't select all components

Tags: altium, layout, import, dxf

I am using Altium 2023. I have designed a PCB layout and now want to change location of some components based on DXF file from SolidWorks. But when I import a DXF file on a mechanical layer, then I can't select all components and move them on top of my existing PCB layout so that I can precisely update the position of some components. Any thoughts why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime I've added 3D models to Altium layouts I've done it by adding it to individual components' mechanical layers, not the .pcb file's mechanical layer

Comment: Can you elaborate it? DXF file does not add 3D models. I am issue with working on DXF files